# Edit Text from Reality Composer

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I'm trying to change text from a text box in Reality Composer to something else via an in-app text box. Not sure if this is possible, but any clues should be useful; thank you!

Used GPT to help me, as I couldn't figure out how to do it.